# How do I get the click function to work on first click

Tags: jquery

I have this script.  It works great if the topic is already liked, but if it has never been marked liked, you need to double click for it to show the user has liked.  How do I get it to work the first time.  Its a continuation from old conversation I had gotten some great help from on here [old conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158244/how-do-i-change-id-of-a-element-every-time-it-is-clicked-with-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#like<? echo $msgID;?>").click(function(){                                      
        var isLike = $(this).text() === "Like",
        url = isLike ? "status-updates/like.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>&user=<? echo $session->username;?>" : "status-updates/unlike.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>&user=<? echo $session->username;?>";
    $.post(url + "?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>&user=<? echo $session->username;?>", $(this).serialize());
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#likeDiv<? echo $msgID;?>").load('status-updates/like-count.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>');
        $(".whoLikes<? echo $msgID;?>").load('status-updates/who-likes.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>');
        $("#like<? echo $msgID;?>").text(isLike ? "Unlike" : "Like");
    }, 500);                                   
});     
});
```

Comment: whats with the php tags in the jquery selectors?

Comment: the php tags are the unique id of each status that the user is clicking to like

Comment: It is ALWAYS useful to see the rendered code in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem may come down to these lines:

```
var isLike = $(this).text() === "Like";
url = isLike ? "status-updates/like.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>&user=<? echo $session->username;?>" : "status-updates/unlike.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>&user=<? echo $session->username;?>";
```

or, in a non-very-long-scrolling-way,

```
var isLike = $(this).text() === "Like";
url = isLike ? <like URL> : <unlike URL>;
```

In other words, when the text already says "Like", the URL being `POST`ed to is the one that actually does the "like".

Incidentally, there is a neater way to perform the delay you're invoking with your `setTimeout`, which seems designed to wait half a second - sufficient, you're hoping, for the `post` to complete - before running. Instead, you can simply run the code once the POST has completed by using the third parameter of `$.post`:

```
$.post( <url>, <data>, 
        function () {
          $("#likeDiv<? echo $msgID;?>").load('status-updates/like-count.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>');
          $(".whoLikes<? echo $msgID;?>").load('status-updates/who-likes.php?status_id=<? echo $msgID;?>');
          $("#like<? echo $msgID;?>").text(isLike ? "Unlike" : "Like");
        }
);
```